# Send threaded message but also send to channel

Tags: python, rocket.chat

When sending a message, one can pass the `tmid` argument to the API to post said message to the thread of another message:

```py
from rocketchat_API.rocketchat import RocketChat

rocket = RocketChat(server_url="(...)", user_id="...", auth_token="...")
room = "#my-channel"
response = rocket.chat_post_message("A message", room_id=room)
tmid = response.json()['message']['_id']

rocket.chat_post_message("A message in the previous message thread", room_id=room, tmid=tmid)
```

This is equivalent to the [`message.tmid` parameter of the `/api/v1/chat.sendMessage`](/api/v1/chat.sendMessage) entry point.

On the interface for posting messages in a thread, there is a checkbox `Also send to channel`:

[image: Also send to channel checkbox]

But I can't find any equivalent either in the Python library or in the REST API documentation.

## Question

How can I send a threaded message programmatically, that is also sent to the channel as if the above checkmark was ticked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Finally found it by searching the [Rocket.Chat source code](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/4d12361e24b3158919bc0a45212170da86c7f16e/app/lib/server/functions/sendMessage.js#L141).
You can pass a `tshow` parameter (must be set to `true`), which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely the accepted answer is not working for me. According to the [documentation](https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api/endpoints/messaging/chat-endpoints/postmessage), `tshow` is supposed to be `true` by default, even if not specified. However, no matter what I do, the message is always sent to the thread and not to the channel.

I'm also using `rocketchat_API` Python library's [`chat_post_message`](https://github.com/jadolg/rocketchat_API/blob/f54db77bcf091fc1a9e0c796c248bb0bb8b7683e/rocketchat_API/APISections/chat.py#L6-L22) method, which seems to transparently send all parameters to the API. I tried the following combinations:

```
rocket.chat_post_message("Replying to the thread", room_id=room, tmid=tmid)
rocket.chat_post_message("Replying to the thread", room_id=room, tmid=tmid, tshow=True)
rocket.chat_post_message("Replying to the thread", room_id=room, tmid=tmid, tshow=False)
```

The result was always the same: the message is posted to the thread, but not to the chatroom.

I would be grateful to anyone who could explain how to make this work.